# Starpy connection randomly closing itself

Tags: python, twisted

I have an application which uses the newest version of starpy and works well for most of the time on most machines it is being used, but randomly stops on some of them.

What happens: The factory stops itself (  Stopping factory  ) and an error is thrown.
The error given is: " sequence index must be integer, not 'str' ", which doens't seem to be anything with my code.
Sometimes this error is preceded by the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 797, in emit
[AMIProtocol,client]     stream.write(fs % msg)
[AMIProtocol,client] IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

The code randomly throws an error in one of the two following partial codes:
Notes: I'm using the " @defer.inlineCallbacks " decorator and the variable client contains the connection.

```
try:
    dndExtensions = []
    dnd = yield client.command ( 'database show DND' )
    for extension in dnd:
        if 'DND' in extension:
            dndExtensions.append ( extension.split ( '/DND/' )[1].split (' ')[0] )
except Exception, e:
    # error ...


try:
    lunchExtensions = []
    lunch = yield client.command ( 'database show Lunch' )
    for extension in lunch:
        if 'Lunch' in extension:
            lunchExtensions.append ( extension.split ( '/Lunch/' )[1].split (' ')[0] )
except Exception, e:
    # error ...
```

Any idea of what might be happening?

Comment: where's the traceback? Do you expect us to get it with our magic balls?

Comment: There is no traceback, all the error messages that appear are on the post. The error that always appear ( sequence index must be integer, not 'str' ) doesn't have any traceback at all.

The stream.write error have only the lines I posted.